# SQL - How to Order By before performing calculation

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT Table1.NUMBER_ID,
       Table1.ACCOUNT,
       Table1.NAME_CODE,
       Table1.TIME,
       Table1.DATE,
       Table2.UNIT_LABEL, 
       Table1.TIME - NVL(LAG ( Table1.TIME ) OVER ( ORDER BY Table1.TIME ), Table1.TIME) diff
FROM   Table2
       INNER JOIN Table1
       ON Table2.NAME = Table1.NAME_CODE 
WHERE  DATE >= trunc(sysdate - 1) 
AND    UNIT_LABEL = 'KG'
ORDER BY
       Table1.NAME_CODE,
       Table1.TIME
```

Hi,
I have the above SQL code which allows me to get the difference in purchase times for items with Unit Label "KG". I am looking to get the difference between purchase times in each NAME_CODE, so I would like to order by NAME_CODE before performing the calculation to get the lag difference in purchase time.

My PL/SQL code is getting the information from Oracle. This code, at the moment, is performing the lag time difference calculation and then sorting the data which is not what I want. I need it to sort the data by NAME_CODE first and then get the lags in purchase times so I can work with it per NAME_CODE rather than everything that has a UNIT_LABEL of "KG"

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. **Edit** your question and add it as formatted text. Also: there is no PL/SQL in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `PARTITION BY` clause in the `LAG` [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm):

```
SELECT Table1.NUMBER_ID,
       Table1.ACCOUNT,
       Table1.NAME_CODE,
       Table1.TIME,
       Table1.DATE,
       Table2.UNIT_LABEL, 
       Table1.TIME - NVL(LAG ( Table1.TIME ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Table1.NAME_CODE ORDER BY Table1.TIME ), Table1.TIME) diff
FROM   Table2
       INNER JOIN Table1
       ON Table2.NAME = Table1.NAME_CODE 
WHERE  DATE >= trunc(sysdate - 1) 
AND    UNIT_LABEL = 'KG'
ORDER BY
       Table1.NAME_CODE,
       Table1.TIME
```

Comment: If an answer solves your problem then you can mark that answer as accepted to indicate the question is closed.

Comment: Done now, sorry I'm new to this. Thanks again for the help